# Catching custom error

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, foundry, custom-errors, forge

I want to catch a custom defined error in my Foundry tests. Before I was using require and the following code worked:

```
    try pathRegistry.swap(WETH, LUSD, amountIn, type(uint256).max) {
        assertTrue(false, "swap(..) should revert when amountOut <  amountIn.");
    } catch Error(string memory reason) {
        assertEq(reason, "INSUFFICIENT_AMOUNT_OUT");
    }
```

After replacing this require statement

`require(amountOutMin <= amountOut, "INSUFFICIENT_AMOUNT_OUT");`

with

`if (amountOut < amountOutMin) revert InsufficientAmountOut();`

the catch execution path no longer gets executed.

I managed to get the catch part executed using the following code:

```
    try pathRegistry.swap(WETH, LUSD, amountIn, type(uint256).max) {
        assertTrue(false, "swap(..) should revert when amountOut <  amountIn.");
    } catch (bytes memory reason) {
        emit log_string(string(reason));
    }
```

However an issue with this code is that string(reason) is equal to `�)p�` and I would like to test that specifically the `InsufficientAmountOut` error got thrown.

How would I solve this?
Thank you

EDIT:
According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/101784/61123) errors are ABI encode. For this reason I assume that I should catch the error with `catch (bytes memory reason)`. The issue I am now facing is that I don't know how to verify that `bytes memory reason` can actually be decoded as `error InsufficientAmountOut()`. I found a [blog post](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/) where the author explains how to decode custom errors in javascript. However I don't know how to do it in Solidity. Thanks

Comment: Did you try catching the error `InsufficientAmountOut`?

Comment: Hello, I have tried that but it seems solidity 0.8.10 syntax simply doesn't allow that. This is the error message: `TypeError: Invalid catch clause name. Expected either catch (...), catch Error(...), or catch Panic(...).`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLUTION 1:

Best solution is using `expectRevert` cheat code from [forge-std](https://github.com/foundry-rs/forge-std/blob/d76af36c2878d598d6b63b8af4df48ad91be6b61/src/Vm.sol#L44):

```
vm.expectRevert(ExampleBridgeContract.InvalidCaller.selector);
exampleBridge.convert(empty, empty, empty, empty, 0, 0, 0, address(0));
```

If you are using an error with parameters pass calldata instead of selector to the `vm.expectRevert(...)` method:

```
vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSignature("IncorrectStatus(uint8,uint8)", 1, 0));
```

SOLUTION 2:

```
    try pathRegistry.swap(WETH, LUSD, amountIn, type(uint256).max) {
        assertTrue(false, "swap(..) should revert when amountOut <  amountIn.");
    } catch (bytes memory reason) {
        bytes4 desiredSelector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("InsufficientAmountOut(uint256,uint256)")));
        bytes4 receivedSelector = bytes4(reason);
        assertEq(desiredSelector, receivedSelector);
    }
```

Since custom errors are encoded the same way functions are, `bytes memory reason` contains function/error selector and the encoded values. I don't want to work with the values so I simply verify the selector. To do that I convert `bytes memory reason` to `bytes4` type which removes all the bytes related to the encoded values and leaves only the selector in place. Then I simply compare with assertEq whether the selector really corresponds to the custom error selector which is supposed to be thrown in this test.

EDIT:
As @Ismael pointed out it's possible to receive the selector directly from the error definition. The code then would look like this:

```
    try pathRegistry.swap(WETH, LUSD, amountIn, type(uint256).max) {
        assertTrue(false, "swap(..) should revert when amountOut <  amountIn.");
    } catch (bytes memory reason) {
        bytes4 expectedSelector = PathRegistry.InsufficientAmountOut.selector;
        bytes4 receivedSelector = bytes4(reason);
        assertEq(expectedSelector, receivedSelector);
    }
```

Comment: Nice work! The documentations about [try/catch](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/control-structures.html#try-catch) has some details. If you have the error defined as `error InsufficientAmountOut(uint256,uint256)` then you could use `InsufficientAmountOut.selector`. To decode the parameters you could use `abi.decode` after skipping the first 4 bytes.

Comment: Getting the selector from the error definition looks a bit less "hacky". Thanks Ismael