# Solidity: How to decode / trace / search custom error byte code

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, bytes

I ran into this `Custom Error` during my Foundry test:

`[FAIL. Reason: Custom Error cd786059:(0xF628...)]`

and I had no idea about what it means...
then I figured out where it went wrong after tracing back to this Solidity source code:

```
revert AddressInsufficientBalance(address(this));
```

Then I figured out how to confirm this error without using Foundry's `expectRevert()`:

```
        bytes4 errorSignature = 0xcd786059;//must prefix "0x"
        bytes4 desiredSelector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("AddressInsufficientBalance(address)")));
        console.log(errorSignature == desiredSelector);
```

But that is not an efficient way to solve this, especially if I have a large Solidity codebase.

How can I quickly search and find out where Solidity Custom Error codes come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, user error codes are selectors on them, encoded just as the function calls.
That is, if you have an error defined

```
error InsufficientBalance(uint256 available, uint256 required);
```

The error data will be encoded in the same way as the ABI encoding for function calls, i.e.

```
abi.encodeWithSignature("InsufficientBalance(uint256,uint256)", balance[msg.sender], amount)
```

The compiler also includes all errors that the contract can generate in the ABI-JSON of the contract (Except for errors passed through external calls).

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "available",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "required",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "InsufficientBalance",
    "type": "error"
},
```

How to track errors in Foundry, see here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/125296/99256.